# Fixing TicTacToe for NxN board

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying enhance tic tac toe game for NxN board. It works fine with 3x3 board but win method doesn't work with NxN board.
It has a win method which works fine with 3x3 board but when increased the size to 4 it didn't work.
win() looks like this:

```
win = function (score) {
  for (var i = 0; i < wins.length; i += 1) {
    if ((wins[i] & score) === wins[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/qTKkb/)

Comment: I'd approach the solution from a different angle: look for N in a row(n ways horizontal, n ways vertical, and 2 ways diagonal).

Comment: Is this a **[homework question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578372/)**?